# How to indent text in a select drop down menu using PHP & CSS? [REPHRASED]

Tags: php, mysql, css, xhtml

I asked a similar question earlier but I'll ask it again in a different way. How can I indent categories and endless sub categories that I have in a select drop down menu using PHP & CSS?

Here is my PHP code.

```
while (list($id, $parent_id, $category) = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_NUM)) {

    // Add to the select menu:
    echo '<option value="' . $id . '">' . $category . '</option>\n';

}
```

Here is the output.

```
   1. Apple
   2. Arts & Entertainment
         1. Amusement
         2. Art
         3. Artists
               1. A
                     1. a1
                     2. a2
               2. B
               3. C
               4. D
   3. Automotive
   4. Network
   5. Server
   6. Web Design
         1. CSS
         2. HTML
```

The numbers are just there to see the categories and sub categories easier.

Comment: Please choose some answer in another question

Comment: @Michael Robinson Here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481966/how-to-indent-text-in-a-select-drop-down-menu-using-css

Comment: Thanks, had a look. What is it that you want? If you want a select with indented options then you do need to do some 'hacky' things and use recursion. It isn't trivial. If you just want a pretty drop down and know exactly how many items / children it will contain, then I'd consider Yi Jiang's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481966/how-to-indent-text-in-a-select-drop-down-menu-using-css/3482079#3482079

Comment: @Michael Robinson I wanted to indent my categories in the select drop down menu so it can make it easier for me to know where I'm adding my new category too.

Comment: The reason I stopped typing is that you've asked this exact question 3 times now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the past I've done this by prepending `&nbsp;` to the content of each nested option.

```
$spacer = '&nbsp;&nbsp;';

while (list($id, $parent_id, $category) = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_NUM)) {

    $padding = str_repeat($spacer, $depth);

    // Add to the select menu:
    echo '<option value="' . $id . '">' . $padding . $category . '</option>\n';

}
```

Where `$depth` represents the 'steps' an option should be indented.

The way I accomplished this was to first put my options into a multidimensional array where children are stored as an array of their parent's...

Like this:

```
Array( 
     1 => Array( 
          'name' => 'Apple'
          ),
     2 => 'Arts & Entertainment',
          'children' => Array(
               1 => Array(
                    'name' => 'Amusement'
                    ),
               2 => Array(
                    'name' => 'Art'
                    ),
               3 => Array(
                    'name' => 'Artists'
                    'children' => Array(
                         1 => Array(
                              'name' => 'A',
                              'children' => Array(
                                   1 => Array(
                                         'name' => 'a1'
                                    )
                              )
                         )
                    )
               )
          )
     )
 )
```

Then I run through the array with a recursive function that steps into each nested array (if present) and appends the `$padding` to the `'name'` value, wraps the option tags around it then returns it.  The returned string is appended to the return from all previous calls, and you're left with an indented option menu. Magic.

Comment: how would I do this for give for my ignorance.

Comment: you need to tell him how to make the MySQL result into an array like that first.

Comment: @Mark Tomlin I was going to, but then another SO user commented on the question that he should accept one of those answers, waiting to see if Topera will reply with a link to that question so I can decide whether to continue not working and typing an answer or if mudFLAP should indeed accept one of those answers.

Comment: The reason I stopped typing is because you keep opening the same question over and over...